# Angular material dialog

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I use ECMAScript 6 for buiding my cod and I tried to make a dialog where the template has a component and I can't fint a way to work
This is my HTML :

```
<div>
    <md-button ng-click="rq.openRequestDialog()">Open Dialog</md-button>
</div>
```

This is my JS:

```
class RequestsController{
    constructor($scope,$mdDialog){
        'ngInject';
        this.$scope = $scope;
        this.$mdDialog = $mdDialog;
    }
    openRequestDialog() {
        console.log("dialog ->", this.$mdDialog);
        this.$mdDialog.show({
            template: '<requestDialog request="rd.openRequestDialog()"></requestDialog>',
            clickOutsideToClose: true,
            bindToController: true,
            controllerAs: 'rd',
            controller:RequestDialogController
        });
    };

    $onInit(){
    }
}

export const RequestsComponent = {
    templateUrl: './views/app/components/requests/requests.component.html',
    controller: RequestsController,
    controllerAs: 'rq',
    bindings: {}
};
```

This is the RequestDialogController:

```
class RequestDialogController{
    constructor($mdDialog){
        'ngInject';
        this.$mdDialog = $mdDialog;

        //
    }
    openRequestDialog() {
        console.log("works ->");
    }
    closeRequestDialog(){
        console.log("close ->");
        // this.$mdDialog.cancel('Close');
    }
    $onInit(){
    }
}

export const RequestDialogComponent = {
    templateUrl: './views/app/components/requestDialog/requestDialog.component.html',
    controller: RequestDialogController,
    controllerAs: 'rd',
    bindings: {
        request:'<'
    }
}
```

My website is a SPA(Laravel - backend Angular - frontend ) one and I compile all my files ,the components are in separate folders(each component has his own folder(html,js,css))

I can't make it work ,the error is

```
ReferenceError: RequestDialogController is not defined
    at RequestsController.openRequestDialog (eval at <anonymous> (final.js:127253), <anonymous>:14:20)
    at fn (eval at compile (final.js:15156), <anonymous>:4:173)
    at callback (final.js:26744)
    at Scope.$eval (final.js:17972)
    at Scope.$apply (final.js:18072)
    at Scope.scopePrototype.$apply (hint.js:1427)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (final.js:26749)
    at defaultHandlerWrapper (final.js:3613)
    at HTMLButtonElement.eventHandler (final.js:3601)
```

,any suggestions?

Comment: RequestDialogController is not exported, but you're using it in the RequestsController class (which, I guess, is in another ES6 module).

Comment: Cant you be more specific?What do you mean "is not exported"?

Comment: If you want to use your controller in another JS module (i.e. another JS file), you need `export class RequestDialogController`instead of `class RequestDialogController`. And you need to impirt it in the other files.

Comment: Thanks for help ,I fixed the problem .Wasn't what you sayd the problem.

Comment: @Wolffyx How did you fix it?

Comment: If you read my code you will see that i added the component like this `<requestDialog></requestDialog>` but the component wasn't load .In my index.component.js I had this `.component('requestDialog', RequestDialogComponent)` and to load the component I needed to add `-` between words ,like this `<request-Dialog></request-Dialog>`, that's how i fixed the problem .Hope this helps!